# Computation of a complicated limit

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Good morning to everyone! I don't know how to compute this type of limit... I got stuck at $arctan$. The limit is the following:
$$ \lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\sin \:\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)-e^{-x}}{ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\arctan \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}\right)$$
$$\arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = 1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - o((1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right))^2) $$ and here I got stuck. The rest of the limit was easy to do: only if would figure out how to do the limit of the $arctan$
$$ \sin \:\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2x^2} +o(\frac{1}{2x^2}) $$
$$ e^{-x} = o(\frac{1}{2x^2}) $$
$$ ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{2x^4} + \frac{1}{3x^6} + o(\frac{1}{x^4}) $$
$$ \arctan \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \frac{1}{x^2} +o(\frac{1}{x^4}) $$

Comment: @Yves Daoust However, $\frac{1}{2x^4}$ from $\ln$ is dominating in the denominator, so it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $t=\dfrac1{x^2}$ and dropping the negative exponential (smaller than any power), we have

$$ \lim _{t\to 0}\frac{\arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\sqrt{t}\right)\right)-\sin(\frac t2)}{\ln\left(1+t\right)-\arctan \left(t\right)}.$$

Up to first order, $\arctan(1-\cos(\sqrt t))-\sin(\frac t2)\approx\frac t2-\frac t2$, and we need quadratic terms. As the $\arctan$ and $\sin$ are odd, they provide no square and we are left with $-\frac{t^2}{4!}$ from the cosine. At the denominator, $\ln\left(1+t\right)-\arctan \left(t\right)\approx t-t$ and we also need quadratic terms, only provided by the logarithm, $-\frac{t^2}2$.

Hence the limit

$$\frac{-\frac{t^2}{24}}{-\frac{t^2}{2}}=\frac1{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{24}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ built around $y=0$, then $$\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) =1-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{24 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ $$\arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\arctan \left(\frac{1}{2 x^2}-\frac{1}{24 x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right)$$ Now, using $$\arctan(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ replace $y$ by $\frac{1}{2 x^2}-\frac{1}{24 x^4}$ if you want higher order than $O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$. If not, $$\arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Comment: So you replaced $ \arctan \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) $ with just  $ \frac{1}{2x^2} $ not with the entire expression. Can you do that. And by that I mean avoid terms and expand only a portion of the expression. Because I see that you didn't expand $-\frac{1}{24x^4}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$